# Change the django-rest-passwordrest confirm view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've followed this [tutorial](https://studygyaan.com/django/django-rest-framework-tutorial-change-password-and-reset-password) to reset the user's password using the django-rest-passwordreset library and I was wondering if there's a way to update a user's field (called changed_password) once their password has been successfully changed.

Comment: What do you mean "if there's a way to update a user's field"? Do you want to also change other field when the password is changed?

Comment: @DavidLu Yes, I want to change a field when the password is changed, but I have no idea how to access it.